# Giving specific id to FormTagHelper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

i've a form written in a **HAML** file  like this

```
= form_tag "ratings_form", movies_path, :method => :get do
  Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating 
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 'yes', @ratings.keys.include?(rating)
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

and i want to give each of the **Form** and the **Submit button** a specific **id**

i've checked the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) and found that the parameters given to

**form_tag** or **submit_tag**  doesn't contain id .

---

the correct answer is adding  :id => "id_u_want" to any tag and obviously it will work
it worked when i did

```
= form_tag movies_path, :id => "ratings_form" , :method => :get do
  Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating 
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 'yes', @selected_ratings.keys.include?(rating)
  = submit_tag 'Refresh' , :id => "ratings_submit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `:id=>"someid"` see if it works for you.